# How do I solve CodeIgniter's 404 not found error?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, restful-url

How can I solve the `404 error` in the codeigniter 
This is my controller **/controller/api.php**

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('no direct script access allowed');
require(APPPATH.'libraries/REST_Controller.php');

class api extends REST_Controller
{
     function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
     }

    //------------------------ Constants --------------------------
 function student_get(){
  $student= $array = array(1=>array ('first' => 'ghali','Last_name'=>'aaaa' )
                            2=>array ('first' => 'aaaa' ,'Last_name'=>'bbbb' )
    );
  echo $student;
  $this->response($student);

 }

?>
```

and my **.htaccess** is :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  # !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
  #  slashes.
  # If your page resides at
  #  http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
  # then use
  # RewriteBase /mypage/test1/
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
  # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
  # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

When I tap the url **localhost/api/index.php/api/student**
it returns the 404 error

Comment: try `http://localhost/api/index.php/api/student_get`

Answer (score 0):

for :- `http://localhost/api/index.php/api/student` your code should look like...

```
<?php 
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('no direct script access allowed');

class api extends MY_Controller
{
 function __construct()
 {
    parent::__construct();
 }

    //------------------------ Constants --------------------------
 function student()
  {
  $student= $array = array(1=>array ('first' => 'ghali','Last_name'=>'aaaa' )
                            2=>array ('first' => 'aaaa' ,'Last_name'=>'bbbb' )
    );
  print_r( $student);

 }
}
```

Comment: yest the name of my application is api in the localhost

Comment: try `http://localhost/api/index.php/api/student` with my updated code...
Your code is not working because you are extending `api` class to rest controller so the url `http://localhost/api/index.php/rest/student_get` will work with your code... with a warning because of `echo $student`... :)

Comment: know i have Message: syntax error, unexpected '?>', expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

Comment: @choofstoon my code is giving you this error `Message: syntax error, unexpected '?>', expecting function (T_FUNCTION)`  ??